# error installed eclipse on raspberry pi 4

Tags: eclipse, raspberry-pi

when I installed eclipse on raspberry pi 4. Eclipse didn't open and show error message.
how can i solve this problem?

---

```
An error has occurred. See the log file /home/pi/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1598254313823.log
```

---------- log

```
!SESSION Mon Aug 24 07:10:02 BST 2020 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2020-08-24 07:10:02.586
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: That is an extremely old Eclipse which will not work with modern versions of Java.

Comment: @greg-449 Should I upgrade the version?

Comment: If you want to run with recent versions of Java you will have to use a newer version of Eclipse, preferably the current Eclipse 2020-06 release. However I don't know anything about the Pi so I can't say how you would do that.

Comment: [First Eclipse Java IDE builds for 64bit ARM available](https://twitter.com/akurtakov/status/1291009644522070016) at https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.17M3-202008200230/ (`AArch64`)

Answer (score 0):

You can try executing eclipse with following parameters

```
    eclipse -clean -console -consoleLog -debug
```

This will list configurations and what JAR files are going to load.

for example: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
comes from osgi.framework=file:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.dist.jar within /usr/lib/eclipse/configuration/config.ini

so we could check existense by typing command

```
    ls /usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.dist.jar
```

if file was not there, try use `sudo updatedb`
to update file location , and then use `locate org.eclipse.osgi`

Here it will list some JAR files, try to use pcmanfm to open each jar file and check whether org/eclipse/core/runtime/adaptor/EclipseStarter.class existed.

i.e. I found that /usr/share/java/org.eclipse.osgi.nb.jar contains EclipseStarter.class
so it would fix this issue by creating symbolic link through command

```
    sudo ln -s /usr/share/java/org.eclipse.osgi.nb.jar plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.dist.jar
```

Or, just modify osgi.framework to point to /usr/share/java/org.eclipse.osgi.nb.jar